# With only three questions so far meeting the required standard this year, is this stack in crisis?

Tags: discussion

While of course I understand that January may be expected to be a bit thin, three valid questions in a month seems extraordinarily light.

Is Interpersonal Skills effectively moribund? If not, why not? if so, what, if anything, should be done?

Comment: freshly graduated? We are still in beta...

Comment: My apologies I thought this was one of the tranch of sites that graduated in December

Comment: Nope, it didn't, and the low volume of questions (and even lower volume of acceptable questions) was one of the reasons :) As for the crisis; the simple answer hasn't changed: As long as unsuitable content is moderated the site will survive and won't be shut down. As for the what to do... if I knew, it would've happened already.

Comment: I find it interesting that the OP deleted their account after asking this question.